# Trouble inserting data to PostgreSQL via libpqxx

Tags: c++, database, postgresql, libpqxx

I have a database which is called `mydb` with a table `People(id, name)`.

I want to insert a row to this table using pqxx C++ interface.

The SQL query is quite simple `INSERT INTO people (id, name) VALUES (1, "Bob");`

The C++ code is here:

```
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char *argv[])
{
  pqxx::connection conn( /* some stuff here */ );

  conn.prepare("insert_to_people", "insert into people (id, name) values ($1, $2);");
  pqxx::work pq(conn);

  pq.prepared("insert_to_people")(1)("Bob").exec();
  pq.commit();

  return 0;
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pqxx::usage_error'
  what():  Too many arguments for prepared statement insert_to_people: expected 0, received 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been a few years since I used c++! Looking at the doc it seems that the argument types need to be declared?  Maybe this will work:

```
conn.prepare("insert_to_people", "insert into people (id, name) values ($1, $2)")("integer")("varchar", pqxx::prepare::treat_string);
```

Also, there was a trailing ; in the query.  I don't think it will hurt but it is not needed.

-g